# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have couples of tables Client, Rooms, and Reservations. When i try to migrate I got this kind of errors:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel_london`.`#sql-142c_6f` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table
   `reservations` add constraint `reservations_client_id_foreign` foreign key (`client_id`) references `clients` (`id`))



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel_london`.`#sql-142c_6f` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

here's my reservation migration code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->date('date_in');
        $table->date('date_out');
        $table->integer('client_id')->unsingned;
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');
        $table->integer('room_id')->unsingned;
        $table->foreign('room_id')->references('id')->on('rooms');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

some said that it's because of my migration order, but I think it's already in the right order and here's the screenshot of it:

[image]

so how can i can migrate it without any errors? thanks.

Comment: `->unsigned` to `->unsingned()`

Comment: @Ijubadr i did that but still no different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spelling is wrong.. `unsigned` not `unsingned` and you forget to use `()`

```
public function up()
{
Schema::create('reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->date('date_in');
    $table->date('date_out');
    $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');
    $table->integer('room_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('room_id')->references('id')->on('rooms');
    $table->timestamps();
});
}
```